# Crete an eval if in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, if-statement, eval

I am trying to create an If that has the condition that, if the eval value is 0 the div wont appear.

```
<%@ if (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Desconto").ToString() != "0"){ %>
    <p><span class="oldprice"><%# Eval("Preço") %>€</span> <i class="newprice item_price"><%# ((decimal)Eval("Preço")-(decimal)Eval("Preço")*((decimal)(int)Eval("Desconto")/100)).ToString("N2") %></i>€</p>
<%@ } %>
```

But i am not figuring out the syntax to create the eval, it aways ends up as some error.

Thanks in advance for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the code inside a `Panel` and set the `Visible` based on the value of the Eval.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("Desconto").ToString() != "0" %>'>
    content
</asp:Panel>
```

Or use a ternary operator if you do not want an extra Panel

```
<div style="display:<%# Eval("Desconto").ToString() != "0" ? "block" : "none" %>">
    content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use # instead of @ -**

```
<%# if (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Desconto").ToString() != "0"){ %>
    <p><span class="oldprice"><%# Eval("Preço") %>€</span> <i class="newprice item_price"><%# ((decimal)Eval("Preço")-(decimal)Eval("Preço")*((decimal)(int)Eval("Desconto")/100)).ToString("N2") %></i>€</p>
<% } %>
```